# Images not showing suddenly

Tags: image, directory, e-commerce, magento2

Images are been disappeared so suddenly from my magento 2.1 website. Images are in the relevant folder in cpanel but they are not showing in the front end or back end. Here this is the link for my site.

http://coolingtechniques.co.uk/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

Within the customer module, in the `authentication-popup.js` file, replace `autocomplete: window.checkout.autocomplete` with:

```
autocomplete: ((window.checkout && window.checkout.autocomplete) ? window.checkout.autocomplete : null),
```

Then, after it's updated, run:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: Thank you so much my friend Sam Infante. If i provide my ftp details could you please do that for me? I didn't get that. So if you could do that for me with my ftp details it would be really helpful.